# What's the easiest way to use reify (get an AST of) an expression in Scala?

Tags: scala, macros, scala-2.10

I'm looking at alternatives to `-print` or `javap` as a way of figuring out what the compiler is doing in Scala. With the new reflection/macros library, `reify` seems a good candidate for that, as shown in retronym's [macrocosm](https://github.com/retronym/macrocosm)'s `desugar`. It even shows how one used to do that, pre-M4.

So the question is, what's the shortest/easiest thing I can type on Scala's REPL to get the AST for an expression, post-Scala 2.10.0-M4?

Comment: Easier than `reflect.runtime.universe.reify(for (i <- 1 to 10) yield i * 2).tree`?

Comment: @TravisBrown Sounds good enough, but I can only accept answers, not comments. :-)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

A lot of things previously defined in package `scala.reflect.mirror` have moved to `scala.reflect.runtime.universe`:

```
scala> import scala.reflect.runtime.{universe => u}
import scala.reflect.runtime.{universe=>u}

scala> val expr = u reify { 1 to 3 map (_+1) }
expr: reflect.runtime.universe.Expr[scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int]] = Expr[scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int]](scala.this.Predef.intWrapper(1).to(3).map(((x$1) => x$1.$plus(1)))(immutable.this.IndexedSeq.canBuildFrom))

scala> u show expr.tree
res57: String = scala.this.Predef.intWrapper(1).to(3).map(((x$1) => x$1.$plus(1)))(immutable.this.IndexedSeq.canBuildFrom)

scala> u showRaw expr.tree
res58: String = Apply(Apply(Select(Apply(Select(Apply(Select(Select(This(newTypeName("scala")), newTermName("Predef")), newTermName("intWrapper")), List(Literal(Constant(1)))), newTermName("to")), List(Literal(Constant(3)))), newTermName("map")), List(Function(List(ValDef(Modifiers(<param> <synthetic>), newTermName("x$1"), TypeTree(), EmptyTree)), Apply(Select(Ident(newTermName("x$1")), newTermName("$plus")), List(Literal(Constant(1))))))), List(Select(Select(This(newTypeName("immutable")), newTermName("IndexedSeq")), newTermName("canBuildFrom"))))
```

Furthermore it is possible to check if a string containing some Scala code is a valid Scala expression and - even better - do some evaluation:

**Edit**. In 2.10.0-RC1 some methods of `ToolBox` have been renamed. `parseExpr` is now just `parse`, and `runExpr` is now called `eval`.

```
scala> import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox
import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox

scala> import scala.reflect.runtime.{currentMirror => m}
import scala.reflect.runtime.{currentMirror=>m}

scala> val tb = m.mkToolBox()
tb: scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox[reflect.runtime.universe.type] = scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxFactory$ToolBoxImpl@9293709

scala> val tree = tb.parse("1 to 3 map (_+1)")
tree: tb.u.Tree = 1.to(3).map(((x$1) => x$1.$plus(1)))

scala> val eval = tb.eval(tree)
eval: Any = Vector(2, 3, 4)
```

The most complicated thing here is the raw tree representation of an expression. When one wants to use macros, the macros have to be defined the same way as shown by `showRaw`. But with some helper methods it is possible to define some not so ugly looking macro implementations:

```
object IntMacro {

  import language.experimental.macros
  import scala.reflect.makro.Context
  import scala.reflect.NameTransformer.encode

  def isEven(i: Int): Boolean = macro isEvenImpl

  def isEvenImpl(c: Context)(i: c.Expr[Int]): c.Expr[Boolean] = {
    import c.universe._
    implicit val cc: c.type = c

    val `x = i%2` = Apply(Select(i.tree, op("%")), const(2))
    val `x == 0` = Apply(Select(`x = i%2`, op("==")), const(0))

    c.Expr(`x == 0`)
  }

  def op(s: String)(implicit c: Context): c.universe.TermName =
    c.universe.newTermName(encode(s))

  def const(a: Any)(implicit c: Context): List[c.universe.Literal] =
    List(c.universe.Literal(c.universe.Constant(a)))
}

scala> import IntMacro._
import IntMacro._

scala> isEven(2)
res60: Boolean = true

scala> isEven(3)
res61: Boolean = false
```

But now we come in problems with path-dependent-types - we have to write their paths explicitly if we want not import them.

Comment: Awesome answer! You went above and beyond the call of duty! :-)

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral: I went inside and fought against compilers, reflections and macros but I still haven't beaten them completely. ;)

Comment: You can use the :power mode in the REPL just to avoid some imports. Anyway, great answer.

Comment: I've noticed that, when parsing and evaluating things from the REPL, the parsed code doesn't see any of the REPL definitions. Do you have any idea why or how to get around that?

Comment: @EugeneBurmako: The comment above (from @DanielC.Sobral) is for you... ;)

Comment: Actually it looks like Daniel has posted a separate question for that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14695609/how-can-i-get-scala-toolbox-to-see-repl-definitions.

Comment: That `showRaw` function I've been looking for about 15 minutes.

Answer (score 4):

There is improve of new Scala version

```
scala> import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox
import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox

scala> import scala.reflect.runtime.{currentMirror => m}
import scala.reflect.runtime.{currentMirror=>m}

scala> val tb = m.mkToolBox()
tb: scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox[reflect.runtime.universe.type] = scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxFactory$ToolBoxImpl@78dc5f15

scala> val tree = tb.parseExpr("1 to 3 map (_+1)")
<console>:10: error: value parseExpr is not a member of scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox[reflect.runtime.universe.type]
       val tree = tb.parseExpr("1 to 3 map (_+1)")
                     ^

scala> val tree = tb.parse("1 to 3 map (_+1)")
tree: tb.u.Tree = 1.to(3).map(((x$1) => x$1.$plus(1)))

scala> val eval = tb.eval(tree)
eval: Any = Vector(2, 3, 4)
```